# Install from Ubuntu Software Center web button

Tags: software-center, software-installation

When I click Install from Ubuntu Software Center from web it asks to chose an application. Where do I find Ubuntu Software Center app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of useful tips could help with this and similar questions.

If you look in the folder `/usr/share/applications` you will see a series of .desktop files.  You should hopefully see something that you would recognise in terms of the application name.

In this case - the desktop file is `ubuntu-software-center.desktop`

Have a quick look inside the file (it is a text file) and you will see a line that starts `Exec=` - that command line is where your application is located.

In this case - `/usr/bin/software-center`

An alternative is to use the following technique:

type `which` followed by the first few characters of the software you are attempting to locate - e.g. `soft`.  Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Hopefully you'll see the name of the application you are attempting to run.  Pressing return after `which software-center` will give the same value as the `Exec=` statement above.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just have it use `xdg-open` for most everything, since this will know what to open the files in.

So just navigate to  -> File System -> usr -> bin -> then find xdg-open
or `/usr/bin/xdg-open`

Find it once and you can use it for a variety of files.